# Customize default vhost in puppetlabs-apache

Tags: apache, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I'm trying to configure apache using puppet and puppetlabs-apache module (https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache). Does anyone know is it possible to change docroot of default vhost from /var/www to something like /var/www/default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible:

As seen in [vhost recipe](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/manifests/vhost.pp),

```
# Sample Usage:
#
# # Simple vhost definition:
# apache::vhost { 'site.name.fqdn':
# port => '80',
# docroot => '/path/to/docroot',
# }
```

Default vhost docroot is bounded to the OS, so if you want to run default host in some other directory, you should disable it using `default_vhost => False` in the apache declaration, and then declare a `apache::vhost` object with your desired conf

```
apache{
   default_vhost => false,
   ...
}

apache::vhost{'mydefaulthost':
   docroot => '/var/www/other',
   ...
}
```

Comment: It will create another virtual host with name "site.name.fqdn", but I want to change default virtual host which is defined inside apache class here - https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/manifests/init.pp at the end of file.

Comment: Ok, so you should disable `default_vhost`, and then declare an `apache::vhost` with your settings

Comment: And how to do that? )

Comment: you can also set your new vhost entry as default with the flag `default_vhost => true` as default

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a default vhost it will pick the vhost alphabetically sorted first one.

This works for me (leaving some authentication and alias usage bits in the snippet as well):

```
class {'apache': 
    default_vhost => false,
}
apache::vhost {'mydefault':
    port => 443,
    ssl => true,
    #port => 80,
    #ssl => false,
    docroot => '/var/www/html',

    directories => [
        {
            'path' => '/var/www/html',
            'provider' => 'files',
        },
        {
            'path' => '/media/builds',
            'options' => 'Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews',
            'allowoverride' => 'None',
            'auth_type' => 'Basic',
            'auth_name' => 'myrobotaccessonly',
            'auth_basic_provider' => 'file',
            'auth_user_file' => '/var/www/.mypasswdfile',
            'auth_require' => 'user myrobotuser',
        },
    ],

    aliases => [
        { 
            alias => '/builds',
            path => '/media/builds',
        },
    ],

}
```